# How to identify individuals that don't belong to a training class?

Tags: outliers, multinomial-logit

The frequency of 8 cell types is measured in 100 patients (the frequencies do not sum up to 1). The patients form 4 pathologies established by the physicians. As there might be better markers (cell types) to specify the classes and pathology is not always clear, there exists patients in-between classes. We wish to classify patients who are difficult to classify. Some of them may be at the junction of 2 classes. Others could be from a pathology other than the 4 learning pathologies.

I built a multinomial classification model (multinom() from the nnet package of R).

a) How can I identify the patients who could come from a non learning pathology?

b) How can I compute a confidence index for the prediction result? For the same prediction, e.g. 50% A and 50% B, the patient may in fact be very close to A and B, or very far away, but still at equal distance.

c)  Is there a better approach (I guess yes)?

Thanks for reading.